# C# NullReferenceException when reading array that won't initialize

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an editor extension for Unity that reads a class named Attack, but C# is not throwing back a NullReferenceException when try to set the object.

This is where the problem lies:

```
void OnGUI(){
    EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 60;
    GUILayout.Label("Attack Manager", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

    Attacks[DataStrings.Length - 1] = new Attack();
    if (DataStrings != null){
        foreach(string Dataline in DataStrings){
            Attacks[i] = new Attack();
            Attacks[i] = JsonUtility.FromJson<Attack>(DataStrings[i]);
            NewAttack(true);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the array and what is `i` set too?

Comment: Is the value saved in the array? And can you show where you initialize the array?

Comment: You should debug your code and share the results of that.

Comment: What is `i`? Which line produces the error? Why check for `null` after using `DataStrings`?

Comment: Please clarify your question, you wrote that "but C# **is not** throwing back a NullReferenceException"

Comment: Why `Attacks[i] = new Attack();` and immediately `Attacks[i] = JsonUtility.FromJson<Attack>(DataStrings[i]);` which makes the first statement unnecessary?

Comment: i is a public int within the namespace so that our classes can access it.

Comment: Please describe "won't initialize." If you need to initialize an array and it "won't initialize," isn't that the problem?

Comment: @Dai whoops. That was a typo. It **is** throwing back a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen That was me trying something that didn't work.

Comment: @ThatDGuy: So... On which line is it throwing the exception and where are `Attacks` and `DataStrings` initialized?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i is defined in the namespace because other classes use the variable. Lines using the array return NullReferenceExceptions no matter what. I'm checking for null because DataStrings is being read from a file.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen The lines where the array is being used.

Comment: @ThatDGuy: `Attacks[DataStrings.Length - 1] = new Attack();`?

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen It's that as well as the other two lines that reference it.

Comment: @ThatDGuy: So... Where and how is `Attacks` initialized?

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen It's being defined within the namespace that the class is located in.

Comment: @ThatDGuy: I asked where and how it's INITIALIZED... not defined (or declared).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Attacks = new Attack[0];
```

Will initiate your Array. HOWEVER I suggest you replace the array with a list

Initialize it like this

```
List<Attack> Attacks = new List<Attack>()
```

Then inside your method

```
    if (DataStrings != null)
{
    foreach(string Dataline in DataStrings)
    {
    var attack = new Attack();
        attack  = JsonUtility.FromJson<Attack>(DataStrings[i]);
        Attacks.Add(attack)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's throwing back a NullReferenceException at 'Attacks.Add(attack);'

Comment: Nevermind I figured out why that happened there, but now the line that uses JsonUtility is throwing back the NullReferenceException.

Comment: Change `DataStrings[i]` --> `Dataline`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Aha! There was the problem! Thank you very much!